Wicket ajaxbutton works fine normally, but when triggered with button.click(), a javascript error occurs
Trying to help a colleague with a problem, and I'm kind of lost in the black box. We have some javascript activity that can happen, and at the end of it, we want to effectively check some checkboxes for the user and click a button for them as sort of a time saver. The interaction of what is clicked is IDENTICAL (meaning the same components are being pressed) between the javascript and user-action.
The button seems to be working when doing it through actual user interaction. But when we try to check the checkbox(s) and then click the button, the event reaches wicket, get processed correctly, but upon reloading the page the wicket ajax debug pops up and says:
INFO: Received ajax response (69 characters)
INFO:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ajax-response></ajax-response>
INFO: Response processed successfully.
INFO: refocus last focused component not needed/allowed
INFO: Submitting a multipart form without a timeout. Use AjaxRequestAttributes.setRequestTimeout(duration) if need to handle connection timeouts.
INFO: Response processed successfully.
INFO: refocus last focused component not needed/allowed
ERROR: FunctionsExecuter.processNext: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

Now, there are some quirks here. Because of an unrelated requirement, the checkboxes use a form updating behavior to synch their state to the server. The event draws from that and is defaultformprocessing=false because this isn't the submit of the whole form, just an intermediate step. We don't want to trigger validations.
So to set things, we're issuing an event to the checkboxes that need it:
if(checkbox.checked && !val) {
    checkbox.click();
} else if(!checkbox.checked && val) {
    checkbox.click();
}

And a breakpoint on the server confirms these clicks being received and synching the state. Then later in the logic, I'm clicking the button like so:
setTimeout(function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('createGroup');
    button.click();
}, 500);

Which again, DOES click the button and the event arrives on the server.  I put the timeout around it because I was wondering if maybe the previous checkbox clicks needed a beat to finish, but it make no difference. I even ratcheted up the delay to 2 seconds with no effect.
But the javascript is literally doing the clicks that the user would do. The events reach the server and I can watch the code doing the exact same things it does when the user clicks. But the user initiation doesn't produce this JS error, and the automated JS version does.
The Java event for the button looks like this:
        @Override
        public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {  
            createGroup();
            target.add(AssetItemPickerPanel.this.getParent());
        }

The createGroup() is just applying the logic of the button (you checked x and y, and clicked this button, so we're going to create data elsewhere in the form for you according to our business rules). But it doesn't do anything super interesting. You can see the target is the parent of the ENTIRE PANEL...which...feels a bit overkill. But overkill or not, it SHOULD work. And DOES work when the user clicks.
Any idea why this doesn't work?  We're in Wicket 6 for this app.

I should add - it fails even when I don't check the checkboxes.  So my fear that it might be a timing issue seems disproved.
